# MS Bot Framework nodejs sdk: display long text in adaptive card

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am using adaptive cards to display the text messages in my bot application. I am using ms bot framework nodejs sdk version 3. I am having issues display long text messages. They are getting truncated. Please find the code below:

```
[ 
  { type: 'TextBlock',
    text: 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.' },
  { type: 'TextBlock',
    text: ' Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.' }
]
```

What is the best way to display long text data inside an adaptive card without getting truncated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `wrap` attribute in the `TextBlock` object to `true` to keep the text from being truncated in the AdaptiveCard. I would recommend looking at the [AdaptiveCard Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) for more styling options.

#### Adaptive Card

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
            "wrap": true
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Hope this helps!